# how to find all of the 'a' values for dim(U ∩ W) = 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

i'm struggling with understand what i need to do for 'a'.
the exercise is :

```
i've been given two subspaces for R4 :
U = span{(a,a-1,1,-4),(2,2,1,-3)} and W is the solution space for the system 
x + y + z = 0 
y + 2z - 2t = 0     

Find all the values for 'a' that exists for dim(U ∩ W) = 1 
and show a basis for U ∩ W in this case.
```

i've noticed that W is the solution space for the system above.  and it has 4 unknows :
x, y, z ,t so could i write the system above like this ?

```
x + y + z + 0t = 0
0x+ y + 2z -2t = 0
```

if this is correct .
i next perform reduced row echelon form to the augmented matrix :

```
1 1 1 0   0              1 0 -1 2  0
0 1 2 -2  0  --> RRE =   0 1 2 -2  0
```

and then i find that:

```
W = z[1 -2 1 0] + t[-2 2 0 1]
```

because  z and t are free parameters.
am i correct ? if no why ? and if yes how i find the values of 'a' that exists for

```
dim(U ∩ W) = 1 
and after that to find a basis for U ∩ W.
```

Comment: Your question is almost completely unreadable. Please revise your post so that it is clearer.

Comment: @Robin Goodfellow i edited. thanks.

Comment: @Robin Goodfellow please let me know if its clear now . thanks.
sorry for my second comment.

Comment: Something is wrong with `{(a,a-1,-4),(2,2,1,-3)}`: the vectors have different length.  I assumed that there is an extra 2, so that `{(a,a-1,-4),(2,1,-3)}` was intended.  Correct me if this is not so.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom its (2,2,1,-3)
the vector (a,a-1,-4) should have been (a,a-1,1,-4)

Comment: All right.  It is also (a,a-1,-4), or is that a mistake?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the vectors should be :
(a , a-1 , 1 , -4),(2 , 2 , 1 , -3)

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to approach this is as follows:

Let $A$ and $B$ be given by
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1&1&0\\0&1&2&-2}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{a&2\\a-1&2\\1&1\\-4&-3}
$$
The dimension of $U \cap W$ will be the nullity of the matrix product $AB$ (that is, $2 - \text{rank}(AB)$).  Find the value(s) of $a$ such that this product has nullity $1$.

The space $U \cap W$ will be the image of the kernel of $AB$ under the matrix $B$.

---

We have 
$$
AB = 
\pmatrix{
2a  & 5\\
a+9 & 10 
}
$$

Comment: we solve it in class and it was found that a = 3, 
didnt understand why,
I also edited the vectors as it should have been in the first place.